# Convert System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies to (non proxy) class in C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dynamic-proxy

I am getting some data from the database and storing this in a global variable as shown:

```
//Global Variable
public static List<stuff> Stuff;

using (var context = new StuffContext()) 
{ 
    stuff = new List<stuff>();
    stuff = (from r in context.Stuff
                select r).ToList(); 
}
```

The problem I am having is that the context closes and when I wish to access some of the data stored in the global variable, I cannot.

The data is of System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Stuff instead of Application.Model.Stuff which means I then receive this error when I try to do something with the data:

```
"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."
```

My question is how can I, using the above code as an example, convert / cast to the type that I want so that I can use the data else where in my application?

Edit: Quick screen grab of the error:
[image]

Comment: What specific operation gives you that error?  Are you trying to access some property that uses lazy loading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve the error The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/how-to-solve-the-error-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was due to lazy loading after all.

I had to tell the query to grab everything so that when the context closes I still had access to the data. 
This is the change I had to make:

```
public static List<stuff> Stuff;

using (var context = new StuffContext()) 
{ 
    stuff = new List<stuff>();
    stuff = (from r in context.Stuff
            .Include(s => s.MoreStuff).Include(s => s.EvenMoreStuff)
            select r).ToList(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Disable ProxyCreationEnabled In Your Project BbContext constructor As Follow:

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```