# How to solve "ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection" for a strange situation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext, objectdisposedexception

I know how to fix this problem, but, this error is appearing in a situation totally different to me.

In my MVC Razor view I have the following code that will filter a list of the model, and bring to me a specific object based on the user logged on and also with a field where the result is different than null:

```
@{
    Models.PostOrcamentoServicoProposta proposta = Model.PostOrcamentoServicoProposta.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Usuarios.UsuEmail.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && p.PosOrcSerProStatus != null);
    if (proposta != null)
    {
      // create a div here
    }
}
```

In my **ActionResult** I have the following load

```
using (ServiciliEntities db = new ServiciliEntities())
{
   // include data
   PostOrcamentoServico orcamento = db.PostOrcamentoServico.Include("PostOrcamentoServicoProposta").Where(o => o.PosOrcSerId == id).FirstOrDefault();
   return View(orcamento);
}
```

As we can see, in my view I receive a model that contains a list of **PostOrcamentoServicoProposta** and I want to get just one specic **PostOrcamentoServicoProposta item** according the user logged on.

No problem about that, but I also want the one **where** **PosOrcSerProStatus** shouldn't be null.

And there is the problem, this field **PosOrcSerProStatus**.

The **PosOrcSerProStatus** field is an `Nullable<Enumerable>` and in sometimes it may be possible to be nullable.

So, when I debug my view, I can see that **PosOrcSerProStatus** is null, and, that's okay to me, however, even if I'm trying to manipulate to get only the one that isn't nullable with the condition p.PosOrcSerProStatus != null, then, I get the error:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection
```

**First**: the list of PosOrcSerProStatus is populated in the action with Include("PostOrcamentoServicoProposta");

**Second**: Model.PostOrcamentoServicoProposta contains objects;

**Third**: In all **PostOrcamentoServicoProposta** objects they're populated properly and PosOrcSerProStatus can be or cannot be null.

Comment: please include more code in a actual code block currently it is very hard to follow what you are trying to do

Comment: what is the type of Model.PostOrcamentoServicoProposta? if IQueryable, this code will result in lazy loading and a query to the database, cast it to a List in this case.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Model.PostOrcamentoServicoProposta is ICollection<PostOrcamentoServicoProposta>. This object is already loaded

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is better now?

Comment: This will not answer your question but... My thoughts would be never have a list that can be null (it doesn't really make sense IMHO)... I would always instantiate the list within the parent class and just look to see if there is  PosOrcSerProStatus.Any().

And one other thing... you can do this db.PostOrcamentoServico.Include("PostOrcamentoServicoProposta").FirstOrDefault(o => o.PosOrcSerId == id); instead of db.PostOrcamentoServico.Include("PostOrcamentoServicoProposta").Where(o => o.PosOrcSerId == id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I notice also that you are using LazyLoading... you may want to check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/how-to-solve-the-error-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-l

Comment: @Gwasshoppa the list will never return null, but, in one object of the list, may have be null.

Comment: @Gwasshoppa the problem isn't with preload.. as you can see in my code, I'm loading what is necessary (look the Include line)

Comment: Guys, what I'm talking about is that: I receive a list with object, but, one property of the object may be null, and if I try to put this property (PosOrcSerProStatus ) as filter, I get that error.

Comment: This is going nowhere without seeing the relevant code (classes, mappings maybe). `Nullable<Enumerable>` is an impossible type.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `PosOrcSerProStatus` is a child relationship and `Nullable<Enumerable>` does not make sense to entity framework. If entity framework wants to do a `.Include()`, it tries to instantiate it and can't because it is a null. 
Just try creating `PosOrcSerProStatus` as virtual like this and see if it is solved.

```
// Instantiate your class and at the same time make PosOrcSerProStatus a new list
public PostOrcamentoServicoProposta()
{
  PosOrcSerProStatuses = new List<PosOrcSerProStatus>();
}

// Also make PosOrcSerProStatuses a virtual ICollection
public virtual ICollection<PosOrcSerProStatus> PosOrcSerProStatuses { get; set; }
```

The only other thing I can think of is that you are closing the DbContext before executing the query within the View...i.e. you are using a `using()` in your `ActionResult` and when it gets to the view and you try to do your `FirstOrDefault()` query the DbContext is closed already.