# Return the result of Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a problem with returning the result of DbContext query in a method of data access layer. I'm doing this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPeople()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people;

    using (var context = new AdressingContext())
    {
        people = context.People.ToList();
    }

    return people;
}
```

And when I want to print the output in Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContactsRepository repository = new ContactsRepository();
        var people = repository.GetAllPeople();

        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I know that in the end of **using** block the objects created inside are disposed, but shouldn't

```
people = context.People;
```

copy those objects? Could you propose an elegant way to solve this?

Edit: exception is thrown in `Person.ToString()` in `if()` statement.

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (ContactInformation == null)
    {
        return $"PersonId={PersonId}, FirstName={FirstName}, LastName={LastName}, Sex={Sex}, Birthday={Birthday}, Description: {Description}";
    }

    return $"PersonId={PersonId}, FirstName={FirstName}, LastName={LastName}, Sex={Sex}, Birthday={Birthday}, Contact: {ContactInformation.ToString()}, Description: {Description}";
}
```

Comment: Are you really using `people = context.People.ToList()` there? Or just `people = context.People` as in your very last code excerpt?

Comment: When calling `ToList()` that EF loads value to in-memory collection.

Comment: What is `ContactInformation`? Is this maybe another entity that is linked to your `Person` type? In that case, you will have to do `context.People.Include(p => p.ContactInformation).ToList()`

Comment: Yes, I was using people = context.People.ToList(), but there is still an exception.

Comment: Correct, ContactInformation is another entity linked to Person type, but your code is not compiling because it says that p => p.ContactInformation cannot be converted from lambda to string

Comment: Thank you, I've read about Include() method and this really helped me, the solution was people = context.People.Include("ContactInformation").ToList();

Comment: See this question or many like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/solving-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used/18398729#18398729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lazy loading turned on and you are getting information from a navigation property  (another table). thus it will try to load that data when you access it but you already disposed of context.  either use .include or turn off lazy loading.