# Cannot return single class with multiple list of table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I got an error on view with error message :

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed. ....
```

My view model class :

```
public class TruckLUOrderVD
{
    public raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder TruckLoadingOrder { get; set; }
    public List<raTMS_CompartmentLoadingOrder> TruckCompartment { get; set; }      
    public List<raTMS_Tank> TankTruck { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LTank { get; set; }
    public int LJetty { get; set; }
    public List<raTMS_ShipAgent> Agent { get; set; }

    public List<raTMS_Ship> Ship { get; set; }

    public List<string> service = new List<string> { "Loading", "Unloading"};
    public List<SelectListItem>  modeList { get; set; }

    public List<Boolean> compartmentEnabled { get; set; }

    public string shiptype { get; set; }
    public Boolean multiolder { get; set; }
    public string maxcmp { get; set; }
    public string serviceval { get; set; }

    public string statusname { get; set; }

    public string serviceAutoNumber { get; set; }

    public string[] productnm { get; set; }
}
```

**Finnaly I have Ajax to get from controller action**

```
public JsonResult Getdetail(int id)
{
    raTMS_Tank TANK = new raTMS_Tank();
    raTMS_Ship Ship = new raTMS_Ship();
    raTMS_ShipAgent agent = new raTMS_ShipAgent();
    raTMS_ShipOrder order = new raTMS_ShipOrder();
    raTMS_ShipTankUnloadingOrder stank = new raTMS_ShipTankUnloadingOrder();
    raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder SR = new raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder();

    List<raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder> ListA = new List<raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder>();
    List<raTMS_CompartmentLoadingOrder> ListB = new List<raTMS_CompartmentLoadingOrder>();
    List<raTMS_ShipTankUnloadingOrder> ListC = new List<raTMS_ShipTankUnloadingOrder>();

    TruckLUOrderVD vd = new TruckLUOrderVD();

    using (raTMSEntities2 db = new raTMSEntities2())
    {
        var c = db.raTMS_CompartmentLoadingOrder.Where(x => x.TruckLoadingOrderFK == id).ToList();
        SR = db.raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder.Where(x => x.PriKey == id).FirstOrDefault();

        for (int i = 0; i < SR.raTMS_Truck.CompartmentNumber; i++)
        {
            var c1 = c.Where(x => x.CompartmentNumber == i + 1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (c1 != null)
            {
                ListB.Add(c1);
                ListB[i].OrderPrikey = c1.OrderFK;
                ListB[i].FQTransact = c1.raTMS_Order.TansactQty.GetValueOrDefault();

                ListB[i].AQReserved = c1.raTMS_Order.ReservedQty.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                ListB.Add(new raTMS_CompartmentLoadingOrder());
            }
        }

        raTMS_Status stat = new raTMS_Status();

        vd.statusname = stat.getStatusName(SR.Status.Value);

        vd.TruckLoadingOrder = SR;
        vd.TruckCompartment = ListB;

        return Json(new { vd = vd }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I have try to some entities configuration like LazyLoading and ProxyCreationEnabled.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I cannot get the data via Ajax. It can successfully returned by view model classes not with Json, I need to running this action without reloaded page. I got error like above error message. Any mistake with my Linq?

Thank you

Comment: Share code of `stat.getStatusName(...)`. Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/solving-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used).

Comment: Try using `virtual` for navigation properties: `public virtual raTMS_TruckLoadingOrder TruckLoadingOrder { get; set; }`. The `ObjectContext` disposal error usually related to lazy loading enabled in EF data context.

Comment: You can create a partialview and in this action return the partial view with this model that you created.

Comment: did you try putting `return Json(` out of `using` statement?