# Can't seem to return my model using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my code, built on ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("DeskBooking")]
public JsonResult DeskBooking(string dpStart, string dpEnd, int tmStart, int tmEnd)
{
    DateTime dpStartCon = DateTime.Parse(GetDateStart(dpStart));
    DateTime dpEndCon = DateTime.Parse(GetDateEnd(dpEnd));
        
    using (Models.nhsdmsEntities ctx = new Models.nhsdmsEntities())
    {
        List<Models.tblDeskBooking> tblDB = ctx.tblDeskBookings
                                               .Where(x => dpStartCon <= x.DateStart && 
                                                           x.DateEnd <= dpEndCon && 
                                                            tmStart >= x.TimeStart && 
                                                            tmEnd <= x.TimeEnd).ToList();
    return Json(new { data = tblDB }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

The `tblDB` has 3 rows but still on the client side I get this error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request
> [ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.]

Client-side code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnBookDeskEmp", function () {

    var dpStart = $("#dpStart").val();
    var dpEnd = $("#dpEnd").val();

    var tmStart = $("#tmStart").val();
    var tmEnd = $("#tmEnd").val();

    AjaxReq(function (data) {
    }, "DeskBooking", { dpStart: dpStart, dpEnd: dpEnd, tmStart: parseInt(tmStart), tmEnd: parseInt(tmEnd) });
})

function AjaxReq(callback, action, data) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/" + action,
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function () {
                console.log("complete");
            });
}

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated from a template.
    //
    //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
    //     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace NHSDMS.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

        public partial class nhsdmsEntities : DbContext
        {
            public nhsdmsEntities()
                : base("name=nhsdmsEntities")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<tblDesk> tblDesks { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<tblRoom> tblRooms { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<tblDeskBooking> tblDeskBookings { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That error message is from EntityFramework (the javascript code has has nothing to do with this error). Are you able to show us the code for: `Models.nhsdmsEntities`?

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/solving-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used)

Comment: @Hooman Bahreini,i have updated as you suggested

Comment: there is a missing `}` in your code... it is not clear where does the `using` block ends.

Comment: sorry my bad i must of missed out the curly bracket when pasting it inside SO

Comment: should i just delete the edmx file and create another one?

Comment: Is `return Json...` inside the using block? have you tried eager loading the entities as suggested in the question that I linked above?

Comment: yes the return json is in the using block and i tried the virtual stuff aswell in the link but no luck

Comment: not the `virtual`, I meant using `include` to eager load the related entities?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini, IT WORKED, using the link u suggested, i went back when u said.this was the line that solved the issue in the nhsdmsEntites class: this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; is this code ok to use i mean to set it to false?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the edmx file, i had to delete everything from the navigation properties as this was messing up my namesspace. if you would like more info i can show sceenshots.